# How to only list folders in S3 in PHP

Tags: php, amazon-s3, directory

I know that to get the list of all the contents of a bucket you do something like this:

```
$s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
'version' => 'latest',
'region'  => 'us-east-1',
'credentials' => array(
    'key' => <key>,
    'secret' => <secret>
)
]);
$objects = $s3->getIterator('ListObjects', array('Bucket' => <bucketname>, 'Prefix' => 'downloads/'));
```

Is there a way to only get the list of folders inside 1 specific folder instead of the entire recursive list of contents?

Comment: Note that S3 does not support "Folders". S3 is an object storage system where each object a key. The key, can contain "/"s which the S3 UI parses and uses to give the impression of folders. However, in S3 there is no concept of a filesystem.

Comment: In that case, is it possible to get the list of objects in a single object without getting the objects in sub-objects?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingKeysHierarchy.html

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
    use Aws\S3\S3Client;

    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

    $s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
            'version' => 'latest',
            'region'  => 'us-east-1',
            'credentials' => array(
                'key' => <key>,
                'secret' => <secret>
            )
        ]);
    $objects = $s3->ListObjects(['Bucket' => <bucketname>, 'Delimiter'=>'/', 'Prefix' => 'downloads']);
    var_dump($objects);
?>
```